# Jenkins groovy mail script, how to print only a particular line?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins groovy mail template to mail console after a particular line. For example the code below prints the first 100 lines of the console.

```
<!-- CONSOLE OUTPUT -->
<% if(build.result==hudson.model.Result.FAILURE) { %>
<TABLE width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<TR><TD class="bg1"><B>CONSOLE OUTPUT</B></TD></TR>
<%  build.getLog(100).each() { line -> %>
    <TR><TD class="console">${org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(line)}</TD></TR>
<%  } %>
</TABLE>
<BR/>
<% } %>
```

Like wise I want to print console only from a particular line. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Ok, do you have a question?

Comment: Yes, How do i print from a particular line

Comment: You are already parsing the first 100 lines of the build log. Add a check for your particular line. What have you attempted? What are you stucked on?